# Setting a StateListDrawable as ImageButton/ImageView.backgroundDrawable in a widget based on users choice in the configuration activity

Tags: android, configuration, widget, imagebutton

I'm creating a widget where the user in the configuration activity can select from a variety of graphics to be used in a button (ImageView (or ImageButton) *with* StateListDrawable). The selected graphic will be used in the widget layout when the widget is added. The layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"> 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button" 
        android:layout_width="72dip" 
        android:layout_height="72dip"
        android:background="@null" 
        android:clickable="true">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My question is, how do I set the selected backgroundResource in the ImageButton shown in the widget based on the users choice in the configuration activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question here. It seems like it's not possible to set a StateListDrawable in RemoteViews via code. The solution for me was to use XML-layouts which has references to unique selectors (I actually made a generator, so that I could generate them easily). This is tedious when working with a large number of graphic elements, but seems to be the only option.